# Compare two string values in a text file C#

Tags: c#

i need help to compare two string values in a text file that are splited by line and also count to that compared string. i have tried some code  but not got it. it takes only one value to compare.How to pass second value.

so the Contains Method returning Bool value how i can count the compared values.

**Text file like this:**

```
172.16.50.70,[17/Aug/2017:08:36:36,GET /login2.php HTTP/1.0,200,1575,-,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"

172.16.50.70,[17/Aug/2017:08:36:37,GET /objections/login.php HTTP/1.0,200,1988,-,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"

39.51.52.189,[17/Aug/2017:08:36:37,GET /objections/css/style.css HTTP/1.1,200,6198,googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:aiou.edu.pk/objections/ssearch.php,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.39 Safari/537.36"
```

**CODE**

```
string Files = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\info.txt");
string[] SplitByLine = Files.Split('\n');
foreach (var item in SplitByLine)
{
    string[] OneRowSplit = item.Split(',');
    GetIP = OneRowSplit[0];
    LapInfo = OneRowSplit.Last();
    string Filess = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\info.txt");
    string[] SplitByLines = Filess.Split('\n');
    string ads = SplitByLines.Contains(GetIP & LapIngo).count(); // this line of code is not valid its only for telling i want some thing like this contain method take only one parameter and i also want to count comapred values
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two text files line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370070/compare-two-text-files-line-by-line)

Comment: What do you mean by "compare two string values"?

Comment: And why not do `File.ReadAllLines` to have the lines split for you?

Comment: @Enigmativity means that for example i have two string values like IP and DateTime i want to compare both string in a txt file.

Comment: @Shekhu may be not duplicate only want to compare string in same file not in another file.

Comment: @AsifShakir - What does "i want to compare both string in a txt file" mean?

Comment: @Shekhu i got splitted array but now i want to compare two splitted array value in that same file .

Comment: what kind of comparison ? are you looking for same value ? diff value or what ?

Comment: @Haroonnasir yeah same value comparison in same file

Comment: @AsifShakir - "yeah same value comparison in same file" ??? You're not explaining yourself clearly enough.

Comment: your file can have hundreds of lines how do you want to compare them only the first and last or each lin with every other ?

Comment: @Enigmativity let me explain . i have text file with 100 rows  i want to make that file distinct on the base of IP and Info . Every row has IP and INFO and also other Attributes . some rows have IP and INFO same i want to keep only one row from repeated IP and INFO Rows and remaining should be delete. i hope you understand .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a distinct list of IP and browser combinations is just some lines LINQ magic away:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("somefile.txt");
IEnumerable<string> fingerPrints = lines.Select(c => $"{c.Split(",").First()} 
{c.Split(",").Last()}").Distinct();
```

You now have an enumerable of strings where each entry unique/distinct. You can write these into another file, or use them to update the original file.

Comment: i think you understand my question little bit .let me explain again to you . i have text file with 100 rows i want to make that file distinct on the base of IP and Info . Every row has IP and INFO and also other Attributes . some rows have IP and INFO same i want to keep only one row from repeated IP and INFO Rows and remaining should be delete. i hope you understand .

Comment: and by INFO you mean ""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"" or similar, correct? I will update my answer

Comment: yes you are right INFO means the string you written . I tried that code but it is only showing IP and INFO in result not a full row because we are selecting IP and INFO only so how to we can show full row with DISTINCT record and that,s good we have reached near to solving problem :-)

Comment: You can use the fingerprints to query the original file with. So run a `foreach` over the fingerprints, and get the First() value of `lines` containing the fingerprint.