# How to get text and count the number of lines with the same words c#?

Tags: c#

It is not known how many lines are in the txt and how many words the lines consist of. How can I get all lines of the txt file. To later count the number of lines that a given word occurs and do that for each word of a unique in the text?

```
...//open file operations 
do
{
  line = file.ReadLine();
  letter_array = str.Split(" ");
} while (!file.EndOfStream);
```

I've tried to take the words, like this. Since I don't know the number of lines in the txt and the word count of the lines, I couldn't assign the values in the letter_array to a new array, is there a way?

Comment: Could you please share your desired output using an example?

Comment: You could use a list instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0#examples also you could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_

Comment: You probably want to split the line instead of a str, like this: `letter_array = line.Split(" ");` ?

Comment: Please elaborate on `how many same words the different lines contain`: let's assume *n* lines - is it *line 0 ↔ 1, 0 ↔ 2, …, 0 ↔ n, 1 ↔ 2,…*? Or just *line 0 ↔ 1, 1 ↔ 2, …, n-1 ↔ n*? If two lines to consider contained `the` twice each, would that be one, two, or four *same words*?

Answer (score 2):

```
String directory = @"C:\Whatever\";
String[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "FileA-Database.txt"));
String[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "FileB-Database.txt"));

IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesB.Except(linesA);

File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Result.txt"), onlyB);
```

You can look at this page: [Compare two text files line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370070/compare-two-text-files-line-by-line/14370155)

Comment: I don't think that's what the asker is after, but it's hard to tell, since the description is bad.